# IExplorer: pop up my own dialog instead of default IExplorer dialog when we trying to load a file from net

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a project which need to customize the default functionality of IEXplorer.
I need to pop up my own dialog instead of default IExplorer dialog(IExplorer run or save dialog window) when we trying to load a file from net.
Is tere any way to do this?
Plz reply.

It's a Local Application.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a WEBSITE? Or a local app? If a website, there is no way to override this dialog, unless you're running a Java or perhaps Flash applet on your webpage. Then you can open dialogs (or "fake" dialogs) all you want. But as far as a native ability to override the built-in dialogs; no. That'd be a giant security risk.

Comment: It's a local application and will be install on machine.

Comment: Okay, so is your local app using IExplore as an object?